# Convert a time to a different timezone using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a time which is in the PHP format: `g:ia T` e.g. 2:00pm AEST. I then have printed in a hidden div below this the timezone in the common format: `Australia/Sydney`. This timezone is the timezone used to output that time (I have several of these times and different corresponding timezones on my page). I have a link at the top of my page which allows the user to convert all the times into their local time (which isn't working yet). When the user clicks this link it outputs their timezone in the same format e.g. Europe/London.

So how do I change the times to the users timezone when I have the time and the timezone used to create that time, and the users timezone using javascript?

Comment: Library recommendations are offtopic for Stack Overflow, but since you haven't specifically asked for one, I'll mention [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - if you're dealing with date/times at this level in JS it's really helpful to have something more than the core Date object.

Comment: Thanks James, I wasn't necessarily looking for library recommendations but I will certainly checkout moment.js. Is there any way to solve this (without writing heaps of code) using the core date object. (sorry I am new to the javascript world).

Comment: You can get user UTC offset by `getTimezoneOffset();` of Date object in javascript viz. the no. of minutes user timezone differ from UTC by which you  can ascertain their timezone

Comment: Thanks Pixel I am aware of this, however my question relates to converting a time into a different timezone not the offset between the timezone and UTC.

Answer (score 0):

While I am still looking into a specific code answer for myself I can confirm from my research that Moment Timezone is the easiest way to convert times to different timezones using javascript. Thanks James Thorpe for pushing me in the right direction. moment-timezone.js has been built specifically for this purpose but regular moment.js won't convert between timezones (at least not easily). Here is moment-timezone.js in action:

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 5am PDT
dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 4am PST

jun.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 8am EDT
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 7am EST

jun.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST
dec.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST

jun.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 10pm EST
dec.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 11pm EST
```

You can find out more information here: http://momentjs.com/timezone/ and also there's a good wiki here about timezones more generally: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info